# Set alignment on HorizontalPanel. ExtGwt

Tags: java, gwt, alignment, gxt

How I can implement following: I want to create HorizontalPanel, then I want to add 3 buttons. 1st button in left, 2nd in middle and 3rd into end. How I can to set alignment for this buttons?

Answer (score 0):

There are several different ways to accomplish this. Here's one that I found more interesting:

```
HorizontalPanel hPanel = new HorizontalPanel();
hPanel.setWidth("100%");
Button b1 = new Button("1");
Button b2 = new Button("2");
Button b3 = new Button("3");
hPanel.setHorizontalAlignment(HasHorizontalAlignment.ALIGN_LEFT);
hPanel.add(b1);
hPanel.setHorizontalAlignment(HasHorizontalAlignment.ALIGN_CENTER);
hPanel.add(b2);
hPanel.setHorizontalAlignment(HasHorizontalAlignment.ALIGN_RIGHT);
hPanel.add(b3);
```

Using CSS `float: left` and `float: right` for the first and last element or using absolute position is probably the way to go for this, depending on how you want it to behave.